# Could not find or load main class ant file

Tags: ant

```
<target name="init">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="apidoc.dir" value="apidoc"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>

    <property name="lib.res" value="resources.jar"/>
    <property name="jar.path" value="${build.dir}/AntLabRun.jar"/>
    <property name="main.class" value="edu.gatech.oad.antlab.pkg1.AntLabMain"/>
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="lib.res"/>
    </path>
</target>


<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${jar.path}">
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </manifestclasspath>
    <jar destfile="${jar.path}" basedir="${src.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
    </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="init">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${apidoc.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.path}" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="all">
    <antcall target="init"/> 
    <antcall target="prepare"/>
    <antcall target="compile"/>
    <antcall target="javadoc"/>
    <antcall target="jar"/>
    <antcall target="run"/>
</target>
```

Every time I run my jar it gives me this error, I don't know what is causing it. Everything else works fine and I've googled around and have found several posts with this same issue but nothing that worked for them seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `classname="${main.class}"` inside the `java` tag of the `run` target.
Also, I think that even when running your program, you need to add the libraries to the classpath.